# TYPO3 - don't show my contents in the Database after installed pizpalue

Tags: php, database, typo3

I need your help for my database.

I created a own content element with the foreign extensions "`sitepackage builder`" and "`pizpalue`" on my TYPO3 ver. 10.4.21.

My codes are written in the extension "sitepackage builder" and I use pizpalue to use a container "2-4 column". So I need to use pizpalue too.

I could see my contents in the table "`tt_content`" in my database (phpMyAdmin) what I wrote in my content elements before installation of pizpalue. So my records were saved. But **after installtion of pizpalue I can't find my contents in the table "`tt_content`". Although I created some variables in the database and I can find them**:

[image]

In the frontend I can see my contents, but I can't see them in my database.
Before I installed the extention pizpalue, I could see my contents:

[image]

Furthermore, the uid is increased if I created a new content before installtion of pizpalue.
But now (after installation of pizpalue) there are until 25 uid and **the uid of tt_content won't be increased, even if I created a new content.**

The variables are structed so:
[image]

(I created total 12 variables in the table `tt_content`.)

in `ext_tables.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    tx_pagesaddfields_frontsideheader TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_frontsideheader3 TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_frontsideheader4 TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_backsideheader TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_backsideheader3 TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_backsideheader4 TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_frontsidebodytext TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_backsidebodytext TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_frontsidebodytext3 TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_backsidebodytext3 TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_frontsidebodytext4 TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    tx_pagesaddfields_backsidebodytext4 TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

I found some different data in CType. I'm not sure, but my CType (e.g. myextentionkey_newcontentelememn) should be shown up by CType. But I can see there "text", "panel" and so on which I didn't define. I think they are defined by pizplalue...

[image]

Why can't I find my contents in the table? And what should I do to display my contents in my database?

I don't know anymore where my contents are saved in the database...

I hope you can help me with it. Thank you.

MEMO:
This is my columns in the table `tt_content` in my database:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm so sorry for the long pictures.

Comment: Are there any columns `zzz_deleted_...`? Maybe something triggered a schema update and your `ext_tables.sql` was somehow not active at that point.

Comment: @Jonas Eberle
Thank you for your answer. Do you mean `zzz_deleted_...` in `tt_content`? If yes, I can find only  a column which is `deleted`  in tt_content. But I can't find any `xxx_deleted_...` I added some pictures in my post. Some variables were added, if I installed the pizpalue....

Comment: Yes, that was what I hoped - the pattern `zzz_deleted_<oldcolumnname>...` is used by the TYPO3 schema update tool. But sorry, in your case it seems the column values have been overwritten? I have no idea what would do that.

Comment: @Jonas Eberle I also think some variables of pizpalue distroy my variables... But I also don't know what does reason. I keep to search it. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my record of my content element in my database now!

If I open my phpMyAdmin, I actually can't see my new records which I added like this:
[image]

But if I clicked on the "CType" column,:

[image]

then my records show up, but not all records which I've made until now:

[image]

And if I clicked the CType again, my records will be disapeard.

Now, I recognized how I can display all my revords in my database (phpMyAdmin).

1. **Open the phpMyAdmin**
2. **Open tt_content Table**
3. **Click on your variable 1-2 times (in my case "tx_pageaddfields_frontsideheader" on the picture) to sort the records**
4. **You can see all records of your content elements**

(If you can display, click one more your variable.)

[image]

The record of the second line on the above picture is my newest record, so my records were saved in my database.

Only the sorting of records is strenge and you can display your records of a variable (If your variable is for other fields, you can't still display. You have to click your variables of a field which you want to see.).

Also, if I close phpMyAdmin and I open it again, I can't see my records again. Every time I open my phpMyAdmin, I have to click my variable to show up all my records...But I think all records are saved in the database.

However, I don't know why phpMyAdmin doesn't show my records of a variable unless I click on my variable.

Can I set up anywhere in phpMyAdmin or is there anything to do ? If someone knows about it, please comment here.

Thank you.